# Excel macro to delete columns containing no positive integers

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have an Excel spreadsheet which has several columns. Many of those columns have all zeroes in them. I'd like to be able to hide or delete all the columns that do not contain a value >= 1. Using Excel 2016 but I also use Excel 2013 and 2010 on different machines, just in case that makes a difference.

I'm new to this so imagine you're explaining it to a 2-year-old; An intelligent 2-year-old, but a toddler nonetheless. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I recommend that you (in a first step) record the things you want Excel to do for you with the VBA macro recorder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`. Also, I'd recommend reading this: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ Afterwards you should be set to provide a first solution to the above problem yourself. If you're still having problems, feel free to come back here and ask for specific advice on something you have attempted to code.

Comment: Start by deciding whether you want to 'hide or delete' the columns then make an attempt at locating some code and modify it for your purposes. You could even record it.

Answer (score 0):

In the active range (range being the column you search for negatives or blanks in) eg Column A set your range, it will use a loop to go through each cell in the column range and hide anything blank or <= 0

Change the letter in ("A1:A5") to the column you need to search through.

```
Sub Hide_blank_rows()

Dim C As Range

For Each C In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")
If C.Value = "" Or C.Value <= 0 Then
C.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
C.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next C

End Sub
```

Please note that you will have to post some code in future.